# How to determine withholding so at end of the year I neither owe more, nor get a refund?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, calculation

A while back I was on a W2 job and I would get a large sum on my tax return. At one point I found a calculator that helped me figure out how to configure my W4 so that I would neither owe nor be owed when it came to filing income taxes each year. The result was less tax was taken from each paycheck.

I've been self employed for the last few years and I am considering an offer that would put me back on W2 and I've been looking for that withholding calculator again but I can't find it.

How do I determine the optimal number of allowances so that I neither owe, nor receive a refund at the end of the year? I do realize it will never be exactly 0.

Comment: Have you tried the [IRS Calculator](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/IRS-Withholding-Calculator) or [this one](http://www.paycheckcity.com/calculator/salary/)?

Answer (score 2):

[Publication 15](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p15.pdf) is your friend. (Although his close friends call him Circular E).

An on line calculator is fine, but 2013 tax software and this publication with let you nail it. And yes, you can zero out, since an IRA deposit (if you can deduct) will let you adjust your income after the fact, when you work on your 2014 tax return in March of '15.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it's what I need, but it's all alien to me.